# How can I get a preview of my Adaptive Icon?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-studio-3.0

I'm currently following the [Adaptive Icons documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) and I would to see a preview of what my icon will look once used on a device using this feature.

I'm using Unity and it only shows squared previews in different sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution for me was to install Android Studio (has to be >= 3.0).

Then I'd right click on the app folder in the project view, select "Image Asset":

[image: Image Asset]

From there, there's a wizard where you can add your own background/foreground to preview your icon:

[image: Image Asset Wizard]

Answer (score 3):

You can try out this app called https://github.com/nickbutcher/AdaptiveIconPlayground which will help you see your app in various different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Googling it up I came across [this neat utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20190526175326/https://adapticon.tooo.io/).

The only caveat is that it doesn't show the app icon near other app icons.

Comment: This is nice and all, but it doesn't look like there's a way to actually try your own icon with it